# Один обработчик на ajax запрос, и запрос с формы

Tags: c#, .net-core

Не получается одновременно (в одном и том же Action) обработать `Ajax` и `Form` - запросы.
`Ajax` работает если стоит `[FromBody]`. `Form` работает если ничего не стоит или `[FromForm]`.
Как сделать чтобы и то и то работало?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([FromBody,FromForm] GroupDTO group)
    {
        var isAjax = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = _groupService.Create(group);
                if (result.Successed)
                {
                    return isAjax ? Json(result) : (ActionResult)RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                    return isAjax ? Json(result) : (ActionResult)View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return isAjax ? Json(new OperationResult(false,"model state not valid")) : (ActionResult)View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return isAjax ? Json(OperationResult.Exception(e)) : (ActionResult)View();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Пока не нашел ничего лучше:

```
    [HttpPost("Groups/CreateAjax")]
    public ActionResult CreateFromBody([FromBody] GroupDTO group) => this.Create(group);
    [HttpPost("Groups/Create")]
    public ActionResult CreateFromForm([FromForm] GroupDTO group) => this.Create(group);

    // POST: Group/Create

    private ActionResult Create(GroupDTO group)
    {
        var isAjax = HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest";
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = _groupService.Create(group);
                if (result.Successed)
                {
                    return isAjax ? Json(result) : (ActionResult)RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
                }
                else
                {
                    return isAjax ? Json(result) : (ActionResult)View();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return isAjax ? Json(new OperationResult(false,"model state not valid")) : (ActionResult)View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return isAjax ? Json(OperationResult.Exception(e)) : (ActionResult)View();
        }
    }
```